# Salesforce Email Alert to Fire when Date = Today()

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, sfdc

I'm having a tough time trying to get this email alert to fire. Correction, I can get it to fire, but not when I want. I have the following fields: `Last Login` and `Last Login Target Date`.

Use Case: I need to alert the account owner if a user hasn't logged into our app in 30 days. I query into our app database on a weekly basis to get the 'last login' dates for each account. I then data load the CSV into our every account's `Last Login` dates on the account object.

I have two workflow rules with one field update for one, and one email alert for the other

1. When `Last Login` is changed, `Last Login Target Date` is updated.
   i.e. WFR: `IF( ISCHANGED(Last_Login__c) , True, False)` and Field Update: `Last_Login__c + 30`
2. When `Last Login Target Date` = Today, email acount owner. 
   i.e. WFR: `IF(Today() = Last_Login_Target_Date__c , True, False)` and email alert: 'Send Email to Account Owner'.

The idea is that if I keep uploading the same `Last Login` date via data loader, the `Last Login Target date` will stay the same until a different date in `Last Login` is updated.

However, today, when `TODAY ()` did, in fact, equal `Last Login Target Date` no email alert went out.

I'm wondering why the workflow rule isn't firing when the WFR for the email alert is = TRUE.

Screen Shot for ref: 
[image]
Any help would be greatly appreciated, and I'm happy to explain in more detail if needed.

Thanks!